# What is the apex court in the USA?

Tags: constitutional-law, us-constitution

In South Africa we have the constitution court which dedicates itself to constitutional matters. The US has a constitution like South Africa has but as far as I know no court dedicated to a addressing constitutional issues specifically ? How exactly is a decision about a constitutional matters made at a national level so all states are willing to accept it? Or is it just as simple as the supreme court in the USA is the con-court by another name?

Comment: Also worth noting that a constitutional court in South Africa is not actually an "apex court" in the same way that the U.S. Supreme Court is. It is a court of limited jurisdiction that can only handle constitutional issues, not the final court of appeal and supervisory court as to all matters.

Comment: If America's Supreme Court justices were held to account, then it would literally be the **con-court**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Supreme Court of the United States](https://www.supremecourt.gov/) is our apex court. Its decisions on constitutional questions are binding throughout the country.

It is not, however, limited to considering constitutional issues, as it may also consider appeals addressing questions of statutory interpretation and rules of procedure. In very limited cases, it may also sit as a trial court in cases where it has [original jurisdiction](https://www.fjc.gov/history/courts/jurisdiction-original-supreme-court).

Comment: That is interesting the South African con court specifically refrains from trails.

Comment: The US Supreme Court doesn't really hold trials. It sometimes hears a small number of original jurisdiction cases, usually disputes between states about land or water rights, but even in those cases, it usually appoints a special master to hear any evidence and make a ruling rather than holding a trial itself, and then the Court will review that ruling.

Comment: Another distinction is that Constitutional Courts typically have the authority to issue advisory opinions (e.g. on the constitutionality of legislation pre-enactment or post-enactment but pre-violation) in the first instance at the request of one of various officials. The U.S. Supreme Court does not have the authority to issue advisory opinions and with narrow original jurisdiction exceptions can consider constitutional issues only in an appellate capacity after lower courts have previously ruled on those issues. Some state supreme courts can also issue advisory opinions.

Comment: Does the US have one central Supreme Court or does each state have a Supreme Court?

Comment: Both. Generally speaking, state supreme courts settle disputes over state law, while the U.S. Supreme Court settles questions of federal law.

Comment: @Neil Meyer However, claims that state or local laws violate or conflict with federal laws or the federal constitution can be and often are heard  in state courts, and appealed to a state supreme court. Such decisions may, in some cases, (mostly if the claim of conflict is denied) be appealed to federal courts and ultimately to the US supreme court.

Comment: @ohwilleke One might argue that the current court seems to take cases without an actual case or controversy at hand...like the EPA regulation suit on which there was no actual regulation in place and the one they were suing about was never going to be put into place

Comment: @Alan The extent to which even the current court imposes a case and controversy requirement is more strict than many state courts and more strict that most countries on constitutional issues.

Answer (score 3):

There is not just one apex court in the United States.

As [bdb484 says in their answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/66558/46948), the United States Supreme Court is *an* apex court, but that is only true for cases within the [jurisdiction of the federal courts](https://www.uscourts.gov/about-federal-courts/court-role-and-structure/comparing-federal-state-courts) or [when appealing from a state supreme court on federal grounds](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artIII-S2-C2-5/ALDE_00001223/).

When the question is wholly within state court jurisdiction, and raising no federal question of law, the state supreme court is the apex court (in some states, this court is named the state "Court of Appeals" or a variant).

There are effectively 51 distinct judicial systems in the United States (one for each state, and one for the federal judiciary), each with their own apex court.

Comment: It's 57 systems, by my count: 50 states + DC + 5 incorporated territories + Federal. Also, two states, Texas and Oklahoma, have 2 separate apex courts, one for criminal and one for civil.

Comment: @user71659, are DC/the incorporated territories really independent of the federal system?

Comment: @Mark They have their own equivalent of state laws, e.g. District of Columbia Official Code, which was passed by their legislatures (Council of the District of Columbia). PR's territorial statutes are unique that they are written in Spanish (Leyes de Puerto Rico) and territorial court proceedings are conducted in Spanish. They have their own courts of first instance, appeals, and supreme courts, e.g. Supreme Court of the Commonwealth of the Northern Mariana Islands.